# Mocking an implementation class with test class within unit test in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, dependency-injection, moq

I'm trying to write a simple unit test where I have wrapped the HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath with an interface and implementation. I'm not positive if the implementation is in the right place.

```
public class FooGenerator
{
    ServerPathProvider serverPathProvider = new ServerPathProvider();

    public string generateFoo()
    {
        BarWebService bws = new BarWebService(serverPathProvider.MapPath("~/path/file"));
        return stuff;
    }
}


public class ServerPathProvider : IPathProvider
{
    public string MapPath(string path)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
    }
}
```

In the test I have my own implementation I want to use, but I cannot figure out how to inject this into the real class during the unit test.

```
[TestClass()]
public class FooGeneratorTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void generateFooTest()
    {
        FooGenerator fg = new FooGenerator();

        //Some kind of mock dependency injection
        Mock<IPathProvider> provider = new Mock<IPathProvider>();
        //stub ServerPathProvider object with provider mock

        string token = fg.generateFoo;
        Assert.IsNotNull(token);
    }
}

public class TestPathProvider : IPathProvider
{
    public string MapPath(string path)
    {
        return Path.Combine(@"C:\project\", path);
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my interface just in case.  Basically I just want to swap out two implementations depending on whether or not I am unit test.  This is my first unit test so much of this is new to me. Sorry if I'm missing something basic, but I've been digging through stack overflow for a while now and can't find the steps to do this part.

```
public interface IPathProvider
{
    string MapPath(string path);
}
```

Comment: A couple of ways: on the FooGenerator class, create a constructor that accepts IPathProvider or create a property that can be set to an instance of IPathProvider. Refer to section 3.4 of this wonderful book http://artofunittesting.com/storage/chapters/SampleChapter3.htm by Roy Osherove for more detailed information on test seams. I also recommend buying the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options.

#### Accepting parameters

In general, you want your `FooProvider` to have a `IPathProvider` instead of `ServicePathProvider` as its `servicePathProvider` member variable.

You can have two constructors for `FooProvider`:

1. A default constructor that instantiates `servicePathProvider = new ServicePathProvider();`, and
2. A non-default constructor that instantiates takes in a `IServiceProvider` as an argument and sets `servicePathProvider` to that.

#### Generic classes

Change `FooProvider` as follows:

```
public class FooProvider<T> where T : IServiceProvider, new()
```

In non-unit testing code, you would use `FooProvider<ServicePathProvider>` and for unit tests, you would use `FooProvider<Mock>`.

This makes `FooProvider` accepts a generic type `T` which is a subtype of `IServiceProvider` *and* has a default constructor (that's the `new()` part) in the where clause.